# Write a piecewise function with unit steps

Tags: laplace-transform

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBRK6.png)

As the image shows I have to write the piecewise function as a unit step function thing. I have tried to do this:
$$1\cdot\Bigg(u(t-0)-u(t-1)\Bigg) + c\cdot \Bigg(u(t-1)\Bigg) = u(t) + (c-1)\cdot u(t-1)$$

but that doesn't get the same as the solution here. What do I do?

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

Your function $g$ will have a jump at $t=0$ and $t=1$.

For $t<0$, you have $g(t)=0$, for $0<t<1$ you have $g(t) = 1$, and for $t>1$ you have $g(t) = c$.

The function $f$ in the solution has: for $t<1$, $f(t) = 1$, and for $t>1$, $f(t) = c$.

The difference is what happens for $t<0$. But the original function doesn't define what happens for $t<0$, so presumably $(-\infty,0)$ is not in the domain of $f$. In other words, your function agrees with the solution function on the domain $[0,\infty)$.

I would say the problem statement is a little unclear.

Comment: After some more consideration i see that u(t) = 1, since t > 0 for all possibilities here, meaning that the question is solved